# Pull out data from inside a constructor

Tags: haskell

I am completely new to Haskell.

I have several layers of information. Each layer is calculated in a unique way, but on the output I have just lists of typed elements.

```
layer1 :: MyData -> [Element1]
layer1 mydata = unique calculations

layer2 :: MyData -> [Element2]
layer2 mydata = even more unique calculations, using layer1

layer3 :: MyData -> [Element3]
layer3 mydata = completely genious layer of profound information
.....
```

So here my N functions cannot be parametrized and should remain detached.

Then I want to run a bunch of similar functions on these layers.

I mights do it in a straightforward way

```
transform1 :: MyData -> [Int]
transform1 mydata = zipWith f (layer1 mydata) constList
transform2 :: MyData -> [Int]
transform2 mydata = zipWith f (layer2 mydata) constList
transform3 :: MyData -> [Int]
transform3 mydata = zipWith f (layer3 mydata) constList
......
```

But here clearly it is inviting to make **some kind of unification.** Like

```
universalTransform :: Layer -> [Int]
universalTransform layer = zipWith f layer constList
```

Ok. So now I need to make `Layer` abstraction

```
data Layer = Lay1 [Element1] | Lay2 [Element2] | Lay3 [Element3]
data LayerName = Lay1Name | Lay2Name | Lay3Name
```

Then I need to make a dispatching collector

```
take :: LayerName -> MyData -> Layer
take lname mydata = case lname of
  Lay1Name -> Lay1 (layer1 mydata)
  Lay2Name -> Lay2 (layer2 mydata)
  Lay3Name -> Lay3 (layer3 mydata)
```

And somehow it becomes huger and huger and the worst problem is that my `zipWith f` wants a list. And in `universalTransform` `layer` is *not* a list. It is a `Layer` abstraction. I was trying to befree `[ElementsX]` from inside of `Layer` but didn't succeed.

I know I am looking in a wrong direction.

So: how can I do that **unification**, but in a proper way, and not like ...ehmmm... me myself.

Comment: I was with you until you said “So now I need to make `Layer` abstraction”. Why do you need to do that? What are you gaining over the higher-order function? What problem are you trying to solve by going down that path?

Comment: DRY concept. To unify the code, that is strongly repeatable. Create `Layer` is not a solution. But I didn't find any other path. It is my second day in Haskell. Maybe I just missed the obvious solution.

Comment: @AlexisKing or anyone else feel free to correct me if this is wrong... it seems to me like you jump to creating the `Layer` abstraction because of the different types of element lists. But if we wrote a `universalTransform` of type `(MyData -> [a]) -> MyData -> [Int]`, wouldn't we circumvent this?

Comment: @mnoronha Yup. My answer, posted simultaneously with your comment, is basically that :)

Answer (score 3):

As Alexis King points out, you don't need the `Layer` type to abstract over the transformations. Just have your function take `f` and the layer function as arguments. That way, you go from...

```
transform1 :: MyData -> [Int]
transform1 mydata = zipWith f (layer1 mydata) constList
```

... to (let's say the type of `constList` is `[Foo]`):

```
transform :: (a -> Foo -> Int) -> (MyData -> [a]) -> MyData -> [Int]
transform f layer mydata = zipWith f (layer mydata) constList
```

This `transform` becomes easier on the eyes if you flip the order of the arguments of `f`:

```
transform :: (Foo -> a -> Int) -> (MyData -> [a]) -> MyData -> [Int]
transform f layer mydata = zipWith f constList (layer mydata)
```

Now it becomes easy to not mention `mydata` explicitly (this final step is perhaps a matter of taste, but I like it best this way):

```
transform :: (Foo -> a -> Int) -> (MyData -> [a]) -> MyData -> [Int]
transform f layer = zipWith f constList . layer
```

The main substantial difference between `transform` and what you were speculating about doing with `Layer` is that with this solution you are not constrained to just three ways of creating the layers, as specified by `LayerName`. Given how you stated your problem, however, I guess you didn't really want such a restriction in the first place.

---

P.S.: If you actually wanted something similar to your `Layer` proposal (which, again, is something I strongly suspect you don't actually need), you would probably have better luck with something like...

```
data Element = Elem1 Element1 | Elem2 Element2 | Elem3 Element3
```

... plus a layer-producing function (that actually produces a list!):

```
toLayer :: LayerName -> MyData -> [Element]
```

The function you give `zipWith` would then be responsible for doing case analysis on `Element`:

```
f :: Foo -> Element -> Int
```

Comment: Yes, thank you so much! I am unstuck. That took me some time to understand, what “Functional” actually means in definition of Haskell. I am having my fun occasionally with lambdas in ruby/rails, but it is just a bit. Here in Haskell functions are all around. They are being passed as arguments to other functions. That's mind changing. It is like to stop seeing things in the first place, and start seeing processes. In OOP/ruby I had a thing and was thinking, what it can do. In Haskell I have a function and think, to what to apply it.

Comment: @AlexeySkoblikov "It is like to stop seeing things in the first place, and start seeing processes." -- That's the spirit. In the context of your comment, it is worth emphasising that if you define, for instance, `g` and `layer79` with the appropriate types, then `transform g layer79` is an entirely normal `MyData -> [Int]` function that you can use anywhere, including as an argument for other functions that accept `MyData -> [Int]` arguments.